# Deleting files from pre installed python folder of mac

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-connector

Is it safe to delete files/folders from the site-packages folder?
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql
The read me file in this folder says :

> This directory exists so that 3rd party packages can be installed
>   here.  Read the source for site.py for more details.

I want to delete the files and folders to get rid of the connector/python i had installed earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
```

Comment: i figured it was safe to get rid of the files. Thanks for providing a way to do so.